# SlimDx FullScreen Switching Problem to Window Mode

Tags: directx, fullscreen, slimdx, directx-11

```
 // handle alt+enter ourselves
        form.KeyDown += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
                bool Full;

                Output ThisOut;
                swapChain.GetFullScreenState(out Full, out ThisOut);

                if (Full == true)
                {

                    swapChain.SetFullScreenState(false, ThisOut);

                }
                else if (Full == false)
                {

                    swapChain.SetFullScreenState(true, ThisOut);

                }
            }
           //     swapChain.IsFullScreen = !swapChain.IsFullScreen;
```

I was using a tutorial on SlimDx - http://slimdx.org/tutorials/devicecreation.php and noticed that there wasn't a IsFullScreen property of swapchain. Therefore, I tried to use the other methods available and came across a problem.
- When I switch to full-screen, it operates as it should; but, when I switch back to non-full-screen, all I see is a blank box that is non-movable.

What is happening? and why isn't there a isFullScreen property like in the tutorial. Is the Device getting lost somewhere?

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  Why doesn't the method given above using GetFullScreenState, SetFullScreenState work?  Based on the documentation for these methods, it seems like they should work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this slimDX world (and posting on stackoverflow) as well and ran across your question based on the same problem. I know this is VB and you're using C#, but I've had success with this, note you'll need your original windowed mode description:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim isFull As Boolean
        swapChain.GetFullScreenState(isFull, Nothing)
        swapChain.SetFullScreenState(Not isFull, Nothing)
        swapChain.ResizeTarget(swapChainDescription.ModeDescription)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not a C# programmer, but here's my take at it:

```
form.KeyDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        bool Full;
        swapChain.GetFullScreenState(out Full, Null);
        swapChain.SetFullScreenState(!Full, Null);
        swapChain.ResizeTarget(swapChainDescription.ModeDescription);
    }
```

Hopefully someone will come along and correct me if I'm wrong or you can help.

Basically, if I understand this correctly, it's not looking for the description of the mode it's already in, which you've done. You've gotten, ThisOut and passed ThisOut and ThisOut contains a fullscreen flag, based on the nature of the SetFullScreenState method. While it's SlimDX, it's all really MS DX, so here's the reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Follow the links inside the article to discover more.

Note that you're supposed to pass Null if you're not going fullscreen. You've passed something other than Null... the existing render target to be exact. The existing render target has now been set to fullscreen. Passing Null (or Nothing because it's VB) as the function intends works just fine. By taking my original, windowed, description and re-passing the mode, which is windowed and not fullscreen, everything works out like it should.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in that tutorial link, we added an IsFullScreen property to the library for this very reason, but it's currently only in the repository (no official release for it yet).

We peg our releases to the DirectX release schedule, and we never imagined it would take them this long to get the next release out. They used to do once per quarter, but we haven't seen a release since June of 2010.

Answer (score 0):

so here is what I did:

```
if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        bool isFull = swapChain.Description.IsWindowed;
        swapChain.SetFullScreenState(isFull, null);
    }
```

It works for me and is a bit cleaner than the other way, you could even cut down on 1 line and just put the .IsWindowed line a in the SetFullScreenState.